# Bind keyup method to two jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to bind two jQuery objects to one keyup method:

```js
let input = [];

input.push(jQuery("#test1"));
input.push(jQuery("#test2"));

jQuery( input[0], input[1] ).one( "keyup", function () {
    console.log("Keyup!");
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1"/>
<input id="test2"/>
```

The problem is that `input[0]` (the first object) does nothing but the second one. I've logged each input and both of them are correct. So I'm confused, normally a multiple selector works in jQuery..

Comment: You are providing 2 arguments. The second argument is used as `context`. It is very different than comma separated selectors in a single string argument

Comment: @charlietfl Should I use two keyup functions for each input? Or is there a better way?

Comment: No. That shouldn't be needed. Provide a runnable [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Done. And now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to create a collection from the two jQuery objects in array

Your actual use case is not very clear though

```js
let input = [];

input.push(jQuery("#test1"));
input.push(jQuery("#test2"));

input[0].add(input[1] ).one( "keyup", function () {
    console.log("Keyup!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test1"/>
<input id="test2"/>
```

Comment: But in case one input was used, the other one should not work anymore. In this case the second one still works after the first one got pressed. The idea is that when one input was pressed (It's not important which one), all errors getting remove so a second input keyup detection is no longer needed.

Comment: For starters why do you need the array in the first place? Can't you just use  class selector and `on()` and `off()` ... or use the two Id selectors if they are known

Comment: Because I've for example a password field with 2 new password fields. The errors for example "Passwords not correct" are displayed at a parent so I need to check the 2 fields for inputs. If one get's detected, the error at the parent must be removed.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to unbind the event handler during an input? Maybe jQuery(document).off("keyup", input[0]) ??

Comment: Yes...just do it inside the `one()` handler

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
    jQuery( [ input[0], input[1] ] ).one( "keyup", function () {
    removeError( input[0], input[2] );
    removeError( input[1], input[2] );
    });
```

Pass the inputs as array

**Update**

As now the complete code is posted. Here's a working solutions

```
let input = [];

input.push(jQuery("#test1"));
input.push(jQuery("#test2"));

jQuery(jQuery(input[0]).add(jQuery(input[1]))).one( "keyup", function () {
    console.log("Keyup!");
});
```

Comment: The selector is correct, so if this breaks something it's likely due to the logic in `removeError`, which you've not shown us

Comment: I've added some loggings inside the keyup function. The keyup don't works because there are no logs in the console.